# R: how do I draw a line with multiple arrows in it?

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering if anyone could help me plot lines in R with multiple arrows in them, like this:

--->--->--->--->

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `arrows`, `p.arrows` and `Arrows` all come to mind. Only `arrows` is in base R, I can't recall the packages for the others, but that should be easily found with Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simulair to DWin this is what I came up with:

```
arrowLine <- function(x0,y0,x1,y1,nArrow=1,...)
{
  lines(c(x0,x1),c(y0,y1),...)
  Ax=seq(x0,x1,length=nArrow+1)
    Ay=seq(y0,y1,length=nArrow+1)
  for (i in 1:nArrow)
  {
    arrows(Ax[i],Ay[i],Ax[i+1],Ay[i+1],...)
  }
}
```

Basically it overlaps several arrows in a line, but does get the desired result (I assume straigth lines):

```
plot(0:1,0:1)
arrowLine(0,0,1,1,4)
```

[image: Multiple arrows on a line]

The real tricky part comes to getting the arrow to got o the edge of points instead of the center. Is that needed?

Comment: Thanks! This partly does the trick. The problem though is that I draw multiple lines of different lengths, so using this creates lines with different spacings between the arrows, like this:

http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/4746/exampleq.jpg

Answer (score 9):

Based on the clarifications to the original question, I think a general answer should consider

- calculating the total length of the broken curve specified by (x,y) points
- splitting apart intermediate segments so as to ensure equal curvilinear length between arrow heads
- take care of minor details such as initial "phase", end-point, whether the arrows heads should be followed by a thin space, etc.

[image: arrows]

Below is a rough stab at it.

```
arrowLine <- function(x, y, N=10, ...){
  lengths <- c(0, sqrt(diff(x)^2 + diff(y)^2))
  l <- cumsum(lengths)
  tl <- l[length(l)]
  el <- seq(0, to=tl, length=N+1)[-1]

  plot(x, y, t="l", ...)

  for(ii in el){

    int <- findInterval(ii, l)
    xx <- x[int:(int+1)]
    yy <- y[int:(int+1)]

    ## points(xx,yy, col="grey", cex=0.5)

    dx <- diff(xx)
    dy <- diff(yy)
    new.length <- ii - l[int]
    segment.length <- lengths[int+1]

    ratio <- new.length / segment.length

    xend <- x[int] + ratio * dx
    yend <- y[int] + ratio * dy
    points(xend,yend, col="white", pch=19)
    arrows(x[int], y[int], xend, yend, length=0.1)

}

}

set.seed(123)
x = sort(c(0, runif(200, 0,2* pi), 2*pi))
y=sin(x)

arrowLine(x, y, N=20)
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a sneaky way to do this without having to plot a bunch of line segments or arrows.
Start with `x` and `y` data as above:

```
plot(x, y, t='l')
```

Then calculate the local slopes from `x[1]`, `y[1]` to `x[2]`, `y[2]` and so on, using some canned routine. Convert the slopes to angles in degrees, and then (calling the vector of slopes `angslopes` )

```
text(x, y, labels=">", srt=angslopes)  # throws error
```

Sorry,  that won't work because, so far as I can tell,  `srt` must be a single value. So:

```
diflen <- length(x)-1
sapply(1:diflen, function(xind) text(x[xind+1], y[xind+1], labels='>', cex=2.5, srt=angslopes[xind]))
```

There may well be a much easier way to do this in the lattice package.

This approach has the cosmetic advantage of allowing you to specify the arrowhead size via `par(cex)` as well as the color - which could be different from the line color, or even varying along the curve.

Comment: @David From what I can recall of my too-hasty notes back then, `mang` is the same as `angslopes` .  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

As joran says, `arrows`

```
 x=cos( seq(0, pi, by=pi/8)  )
 y=sin( seq(0, pi, by=pi/8))
 plot(1,1, ylim=range(y), xlim=range(x))
 arrows(x[-length(x)],y[-length(y)], x[-1],y[-1])
```

If you want to draw a straight multiple arrow curve with specification of equal lengths, then use this function:

```
multarrows <- function(x0,y0, x1,y1,n_arr, ...) {x<- seq(x0,x1, length=n_arr+1)
             y<-seq(y0,y1, length=n_arr+1)
             arrows(x[-length(x)],y[-length(y)], x[-1],y[-1], ...) }
plot(0,0, xlim=c(0,2), ylim=c(0,11)); multarrows(0,0, 1,10, 10)
```

[image]

Comment: That's really just drawing multiple arrows. I was hoping for an option that allows you to draw just one line with multiple arrows in it...

Comment: Thanks! Your second solution partly does the trick. The problem though is that I draw multiple lines of different lengths, so using this creates lines with different spacings between the arrows, like this: 
http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/4746/exampleq.jpg.

I'll try to figure out how to fix this, but I'm not so experienced in R...

Comment: The combination of the first solution and the second solution should make clear that is possible. Instead of splitting up the line within hte function, you just need to supply the beginnings and ends of your segments. Data! We want Data! (and linked image fails to load on multiple attempts.)

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would add a base R solution here that calculates the arrow heads as segments. There are versions to create a new plot or add arrows to an existing plot. Longer segments are split into shorter ones:

```r
add_arrows <- function(x, y, ...)
{
  # Ensure equal lengthed vectors
  min_len <- min(length(x), length(y))
  x  <- x[seq(min_len)]
  y  <- y[seq(min_len)]

  # Calculate y:x ratio
  yx_ratio <- 3*(max(y) - min(y)) / (max(x) - min(x))

  # Create start and end points
  x1 <- x[-length(x)]
  y1 <- y[-length(y)]
  x2 <- x[-1]
  y2 <- y[-1]

  # Length and angle of line segments
  theta <- atan((y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1))
  seg_lengths <- sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)

  # Break long segments into shorter segments
  long <- which(seg_lengths > (2 * min(seg_lengths)))
  if(length(long) > 0)
  {
    n_segs <- floor(seg_lengths[long] / (1.5 * min(seg_lengths)))

    for(i in seq_along(long))
    {
      xs <- x1[long[i]] + (0:n_segs[i]) * (x2[long[i]] - x1[long[i]]) / n_segs[i]
      ys <- y1[long[i]] + (0:n_segs[i]) * (y2[long[i]] - y1[long[i]]) / n_segs[i]
      x1 <- c(x1, xs[-length(xs)])
      x2 <- c(x2, xs[-1])
      y1 <- c(y1, ys[-length(ys)])
      y2 <- c(y2, ys[-1])
      theta <- c(theta, rep(theta[long[i]], length(xs) - 1))
    }

    x1 <- x1[-long]; x2 <- x2[-long]; y1 <- y1[-long]; y2 <- y2[-long];
    theta <- theta[-long]
  }
  # Arrow head length and width
  len <- sqrt((max(y) - min(y))^2 + (max(x) - min(x))^2)/ 20
  wid <- len * 0.1


  # Calculate arrow heads
  zx  <- x2 - len * cos(theta) * sign(x2 - x1)
  zy  <- y2 - len * sin(theta) * sign(x2 - x1)
  ax1 <- zx + wid * sin(theta) * sign(x2 - x1)
  ax2 <- zx - wid * sin(theta) * sign(x2 - x1)
  ay1 <- zy - wid * cos(theta) * sign(x2 - x1) * yx_ratio
  ay2 <- zy + wid * cos(theta) * sign(x2 - x1) * yx_ratio

  df <- data.frame(x1  = x1 + 0.1 * (x2 - x1),
                   y1  = y1 + 0.1 * (y2 - y1),
                   x2  = x2 - 0.5 * len * cos(theta) * sign(x2 - x1),
                   y2  = y2 - 0.5 * len * sin(theta) * sign(x2 - x1),
                   ax1 = ax1, ay1 = ay1, ax2 = ax2, ay2 = ay2)

  # Draw segments
  segments(df$x1, df$y1, df$x2,  df$y2,  col = "red", lwd = 2)
  segments(df$x2, df$y2, df$ax1, df$ay1, col = "red", lwd = 2)
  segments(df$x2, df$y2, df$ax2, df$ay2, col = "red", lwd = 2)
}
```

This allows you to plot arrows as the basis of your plot:

```
plot_arrows <- function(x, y, ...)
{
  plot(x, y, col = "white", ...)
  add_arrows(x, y, ...)
}
```

So now you can do:

```
set.seed(69)

x <- 1:10
y <- sample(10)
plot(x, y)
add_arrows(x, y)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>