# How do I plot lines and points with limited points?

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I am trying to replot the following figure in a more legible way. Observe that I am trying to plot both lines and points. However, the number of points being printed is way too many and the line is getting covered up. Is there a way I can plot:

- Different lines for different datasets
- Different points shapes for different datasets but limit the number of points to say 30-50
- Add the line and point information to the legend

[image]

My plotting code is [here](http://www.hastebin.com/vetotapavu.coffee) (It was too big for SO)

Comment: If the plot is an empirical cumulative distribution function (ecdf), as the axis name suggests, the absence of a vertical segment at the lower left of the plot (there is one at the upper right, for the other group), and the absence of points on the two vertical segments (lower left and upper left), corresponding to the many "0" or "1" values, look weird (I would expect the "ecd" column to be uniformly distributed in [0,1]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need something like this?

```
transData$Type2 <- factor(transData$Type, labels = c("Some Info for P", "Some Info for Q"))    
ggplot(transData, aes(x=Value, y=ecd)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group=Type2,colour=Type2, linetype=Type2), size=1.5) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = Type2), data = transData[round(seq(1, nrow(transData), length = 30)), ], size = 5) +
  opts(legend.position = "top", legend.key.width = unit(3, "line"))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes... Perfect! Almost there. Is there a way to place the points uniformly as well?

Comment: i imagine you could adapt [this procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6904434/471093) to draw points at regular intervals.

Answer (score 1):

You can plot large, partially transparent points: the denser areas will appear darker.

```
p <- ggplot(transData, aes(x=Value, y=ecd, group=Type))
p + 
  geom_point(size=20, colour=rgb(0,0,0,.02))  +
  geom_line(aes(colour=Type), size=3)
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks great but I am not sure this is eps-friendly due to the transparency? Also, I need a point legend so that when the graph is printed using a BW printer, it is still legible.

Comment: There is no transparency in PostScript (eps) -- I thought that format had completely been replaced by pdf sometime during the last decade...

Comment: +1 for your time. Unfortunately, in the academic community, we still use EPS for some odd reason. But thank you for your help nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

The following code adds points more or less evenly spaced, though they're not necessarily actual data points (could be interpolated),

```
barbedize <- function(x, y, N=10, ...){
  ind <- order(x)
  x <- x[ind]
  y <- y[ind]
  lengths <- c(0, sqrt(diff(x)^2 + diff(y)^2))
  l <- cumsum(lengths)
  tl <- l[length(l)]
  el <- seq(0, to=tl, length=N+1)[-1]

  res <- 
  sapply(el[-length(el)], function(ii){

    int <- findInterval(ii, l)
    xx <- x[int:(int+1)]
    yy <- y[int:(int+1)]

    dx <- diff(xx)
    dy <- diff(yy)
    new.length <- ii - l[int]
    segment.length <- lengths[int+1]

    ratio <- new.length / segment.length

    xend <- x[int] + ratio * dx
    yend <- y[int] + ratio * dy

    c(x=xend, y=yend)

  })
  as.data.frame(t(res))
}


library(plyr)

few_points <- ddply(transData, "Type", function(d, ...)
                    barbedize(d$Value, d$ecd, ...), N=10)

ggplot(transData, aes(x=Value, y=ecd)) + 
     geom_line(aes(group=Type,colour=Type, linetype=Type), size=1) + 
     geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y, colour=Type, shape=Type), data=few_points, size=3)
```

[image: shape]

(this is a quick and dirty proof-of-principle, `barbedize` should be cleaned up and written more efficiently...)

Comment: this question reminds me of my evasive plan to make a `ggplot2` geom from [`barbedGrob`](http://code.google.com/p/gridextra/wiki/barbedGrob). I wonder, would it make sense to also have the option to draw only few points when they're very close, like the above.