# Combining multiple ggplot2 polygons / paths

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating choropleth maps of county level data with ggplot2. I want to highlight multiple-county regions. It is simple enough to overlay a path or polygon of a subset of the county map  data, but this leaves "interior" path lines. Is there a way to combine these regions into one group or simply hide the interior lines?

```
require(ggplot2)
require(maps)
require(maptools)

va <- map_data("county", region="virginia")

ggplot(va, aes(long, lat)) + coord_map() + 
  geom_polygon(aes(group=group)) +
  geom_path(data=subset(va, subregion %in% c("patrick", "henry", "franklin",
    "pittsylvania")), aes(group=group), size=1, color="white")
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIiAG.png

EDIT: The above example isn't exactly what I want to do. The code below is more representative of the actual project. The actual maps will be even more detailed than this since they use census tract level data and have geocoded points on top.

```
va <- map_data("county", region="virginia")
cty <- data.frame(subregion=unique(va$subregion))
cty$stat <- sample.int(nrow(cty))
va <- merge(va, cty, by="subregion")

p <- ggplot(va, aes(long, lat)) + coord_map() + 
  geom_polygon(aes(group=group, fill=stat), color="grey") +
  geom_path(data=subset(va, subregion %in% c("patrick", "henry", "franklin",
    "pittsylvania")), aes(group=group), size=1, color="white")
```

[image]

Comment: maybe take some alphahull of the coordinates?

Comment: thanks, @baptiste, for the suggestion. i (think i) figured out `ahull` from the `alphahull` package. the problem is that it includes points inside the region, even at high values of alpha. `chull` works better in this regard but lacks the roughness of `ahull`.

Comment: I see, that's because some borders have only very few points to define them, therefore the alpha hull extends too far inside.

Comment: plotting the points `with(subset(va, subregion %in% c("patrick", "henry", "franklin", "pittsylvania")), plot(long, lat))` gives an other idea: identify and remove the points that are common between the subregions.

Comment: brute force would be to split the boundaries with a given resolution (something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9015298/471093) might help), then apply the alphahull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking at `?map`, you can simply do the following,

```
boundary <- map("county", regions=c("virginia.patrick", "virginia.henry", "virginia.franklin", "virginia.pittsylvania"), boundary=TRUE, interior=FALSE)
```

now, for some reason neither `map_data` nor `ggplot2:::fortify.map` seem to be happy with this, but it wouldn't be hard to extract the relevant part of `fortify.map` and get it in a format that pleases coord_map. If you do, I'd suggest that you file a bug report as it seems that ggplot2 should support those options of `map`.

Comment: this is working pretty well. i used the line you suggested and created a dataframe out of the `x` and `y` components of the `boundary` object for a `geom_path` layer. right now the path isn't closing; when i have time i'll try to figure out why.

Answer (score 5):

If I get you right, you just need to swap `geom_path` for `geom_polygon` to plot without internal lines:

```
ggplot(va, aes(long, lat)) + coord_map() + geom_polygon(aes(group=group)) + 
   geom_polygon(data=subset(va, subregion %in% c("patrick", "henry", "franklin",
   "pittsylvania")), aes(group=group), size=1, color="white",fill="white")
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I think my example was too simplistic. I edited the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify and remove the points at the border between subregions,

```
d <- subset(va, subregion %in% c("patrick", "henry", "franklin", "pittsylvania"))
duplicates <- duplicated(d[, c("long","lat")]) |
              duplicated(d[, c("long","lat")], fromLast=TRUE)

d2 <- d[duplicates, ]
d3 <- d[!duplicates, ]
d3 <- arrange(d3, order , region, group )
ggplot(d, aes(long, lat)) + geom_polygon(aes(fill=subregion), col=NA) +
  geom_point(colour="black") +
  geom_point(data=d2, colour="red") +
  geom_path(data=d3, fill=NA, colour="blue", size=1.2)
```

not sure how to fix the winding order and this sort of thing...