# Is there a way to use selfdefined linetypes in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to define your own linetype in ggplot?
In a line diagram I would like the lines to be displayed as little numbers. Kind of like linetype “dotted” just with little “1” or “2” instead of the dots. 
I tried it with labels, but they only show on the defined points and not in the spaces in between. And I could not figure it out, how to implement it into scale_linetype_manual

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = runif(10),
  y = runif(10),
  z = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour=as.factor(z), linetype = as.factor(z)))+ 
  geom_text(aes(label=z))
```

Comment: You most likely can't do that using `geom_line` with `linetype`. You _could_ interpolate more values and use `geom_text`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adapting [this strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40952554/471093) to split paths into equi-spaced segments,

[image]

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  x = runif(10),
  y = runif(10),
  z = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2))

parametric_smoothie <- function(x, y, sort = TRUE, N=1e2, phase=1, offset=0) {

  if(sort){
    ox <- order(x)
    x <- x[ox]
    y <- y[ox]
  }

  lengths <- c(0, sqrt(diff(x)^2 + diff(y)^2))
  l <- cumsum(lengths)
  lmax <- max(l)
  newpos <- seq(phase*lmax/N, lmax-phase*lmax/N, length.out = N) + offset*lmax/N
  xx <- approx(l, x, newpos)$y
  yy <- approx(l, y, newpos)$y

  ## new points, equi-spaced
  dnew <- data.frame(x = xx, y = yy)

  xx <- c(x, xx)
  yy <- c(y, yy)
  ox <- order(xx)
  xx <- xx[ox]
  yy <- yy[ox]

  ## original and new points combined
  dcomb <- data.frame(x = xx, y = yy)

  list(dnew = dnew, dcomb = dcomb)
}

dl <- plyr::dlply(df, "z", function(.d) parametric_smoothie(.d$x, .d$y, N=10))

df2 <- plyr::ldply(dl, "[[", "dnew")
df3 <- plyr::ldply(dl, "[[", "dcomb")

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(data = df3, aes(colour=as.factor(z))) + 
  geom_point(data = df2, colour = "grey92", size=5) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=as.factor(z))) + 
  geom_text(data = df2, aes(label=z), size=3)
```

Comment: @user3845433 consider accepting/upvoting the answer