# Placing arrow heads to the middle of the lines in R

Tags: r, plot, arrows

I have a plot where I draw arrows from points to points. I would like to put this arrow heads not to the end of the line, but to middle. Is there a simple way to do it other than placing extra arrows with half length of the according line?
My code is this:

```
plot(x, y, xlim=range(x), ylim=range(y), xlab="x", ylab="y", pch=16,
     main="Filled Plane")

for(i in 1:20){
  arrows(x[i], y[i], x[i+1], y[i+1], length = 0.25, angle = 30, col = i)
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example of your desired output. Your current explanation is not clear...

Comment: might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893959/r-how-do-i-draw-a-line-with-multiple-arrows-in-it

Comment: `col = 1:3` makes no sense because just one arrow is drawn in each loop.

Comment: @DarrenTsai yeah I fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a custom function `myArrow()` and add one new argument `cut` to control the proportion of the arrows

```
myArrow <- function(x0, y0, x1, y1, cut = 1, ...){
  x.new <- (1 - cut) * x0 + cut * x1
  y.new <- (1 - cut) * y0 + cut * y1
  # segments(x0, y0, x1, y1, ...)
  arrows(x0, y0, x.new, y.new, ...)
}
```

**Note1 :** The computation of `x.new` and `y.new` in this custom function uses a simple mathematical concept, i.e. the **Section Formula**. The value of `cut` must be **between 0 to 1**.

**Note2 :** The use of this function is equivalent to that of the original function`arrows()` other than that it has one more new argument `cut`.

**Note3 :** If you want complete lines behind the arrows, just remove the hash(`#`) in the function.

---

Plot and try different `cut` value. For example, I use `cut = 0.7`. (If you want the arrowheads to the middle, use `cut = 0.5`.)

```
# Toy Data
x <- seq(1, 5.5, by = 0.5)
y <- rep(c(1, 5), 5)

plot(x, y, pch = 16)
for(i in 1:9){
  myArrow(x[i], y[i], x[i+1], y[i+1], cut = 0.7, col = i, lwd = 2)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since you do not provide your x and y, I made up some data.  There is no need for the loop. `arrows` will handle a vector of coordinates. One way is to draw a full-length arrow with no arrowhead and another that just goes halfway but has the arrowhead.

```
## Some bogus data
set.seed(123)
x = runif(4)
y = runif(4)

## Compute the midpoints
midx = diff(x)/2 + x[-length(x)]
midy = diff(y)/2 + y[-length(y)]

## Draw it
plot(x,y,xlim=range(x), ylim=range(y), xlab="x", ylab="y", 
    main="Filled Plane",pch=16)
arrows(x[-length(x)], y[-length(y)],x[-1],y[-1],
    angle = 0, col = 1:3)
arrows(x[-length(x)], y[-length(y)],midx,midy,
    length = 0.25, angle = 30, col = 1:3)
```

[image: Arrowhead in center]